# Swift: Can closures be used like lambdas to find objects in array?

Tags: c#, swift, lambda, closures

I'm using swift and I have an array that I'd like to search for an object using the value of one of its properties.

In C# I'd use a lambda to find my object like so:
`return myArray.FirstOrDefault(obj -> obj.Name == "Foo");`

I've heard that swift uses closures instead of lambdas, so is there a similar way to accomplish this one-line task in swift using Closures?

I've checked apple's documentation about Closures [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) and everything seems to require writing a separate function. It just feels like there's probably an easy way to do this in swift that I haven't found yet.

Comment: Closures and lambdas are the same. Your C# lambda `obj => obj.Name == "Foo"` will be `{ obj in obj.Name == "Foo" }` in Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift has an Array method named `indexOf` that will return the first index of a matching element given a closure. To return the actual element you will need to do something like this.  The return is an optional since there may be no match so you have to handle that yourself.

```
let element = array.filter{ $0.name == "Foo" }.first
```

[image]

Maybe we can overload Array so that there is a version of `first` that takes a closure instead of void.

```
extension Array {
  func first(includes: (Element) -> Bool) -> Element? {
    return self.filter{ includes($0) }.first
  }
}
```

[image]